# how do you install drivers for AMD radeon PRO WX 4100 on debian 10?

Tags: debian-buster, amd-gpu, dkms

I am trying to install amdgpu-pro on debian 10 kernel 4.19.0-13, and I am getting the following error:

```
$ sudo apt upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
4 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Setting up amdgpu-dkms (1:5.4.7.62-1084971) ...
Removing old amdgpu-5.4.7.62-1084971 DKMS files...

------------------------------
Deleting module version: 5.4.7.62-1084971
completely from the DKMS tree.
------------------------------
Done.
Loading new amdgpu-5.4.7.62-1084971 DKMS files...
Building for 4.19.0-13-amd64
Building for architecture amd64
Building initial module for 4.19.0-13-amd64
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 4.19.0-13-amd64 (amd64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/5.4.7.62-1084971/build/make.log for more information.
dpkg: error processing package amdgpu-dkms
adamluco@lucocc:~/a (--configure):
 installed amdgpu-dkms package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 10
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of amdgpu:
 amdgpu depends on amdgpu-dkms (= 1:5.4.7.62-1084971); however:
  Package amdgpu-dkms is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package amdgpu (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of amdgpu-pro:
 amdgpu-pro depends on amdgpu (= 20.10-1084971); however:
  Package amdgpu is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package amdgpu-pro (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of amdgpu-pro-lib32:
 amdgpu-pro-lib32 depends on amdgpu (= 20.10-1084971) | amdgpu-hwe (= 20.10-1084971); however:
  Package amdgpu is not configured yet.
  Package amdgpu-hwe is not installed.
 amdgpu-pro-lib32 depends on amdgpu-pro (= 20.10-1084971) | amdgpu-pro-hwe (= 20.10-1084971); however:
  Package amdgpu-pro is not configured yet.
  Package amdgpu-pro-hwe is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package amdgpu-pro-lib32 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 amdgpu-dkms
 amdgpu
 amdgpu-pro
 amdgpu-pro-lib32
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I get the same error when trying to install using the install files

I am not sure how to resolve the dpkg errors

I don't know what other information to add to this post so that stack overflow lets me post it, so maybe if I keep writing words it will accept it

Answer (score 1):

The short answer seems to be it's not supported:

https://wiki.debian.org/AMDGPUDriverOnStretchAndBuster2

That page will give you instructions for patching the kernel (assuming you have 4.19) and porting over Ubuntu drivers, but as the page says:

> This page documents **non-recommended** practices such as installing packages meant for other GNU/Linux distributions and manually patching files provided by packages.